# jquery remover en un form todos las propiedades disabled/readonly de los inputs y select boxes

Tags: jquery, ajax

estoy intentando usar jquery para capturar un form y remover en el form todas las propiedades disabled/readonly que contengan los inputs y select boxes, sin que esto afecte a la vista del usuario, lo he intentado con dos versiones, pero no me funcionan ninguna y afectan las Vista(html) del usuario, tambien intente cambiando el .each() por .find():

```
var $form       = $("#formarea");
var $form       = $form.each('input').prop('readonly', false);
var $form       = $form.each('select').prop('disabled', false);
```

Y guardarlo en un objeto para ser enviado con ajax incluyendo los input y select box que estén disabled o readonly:

```
  var   formData    = new FormData();
  var   params      = $form.serializeArray();

    $.ajax({
                    url: $form.attr('action'),
                    data: formData,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    type: 'POST',
                    error: function(xhr,status,error){console.log('Error')},
                    success:    function(response) {console.log('Logrado')}
    });
```

estoy Obteniendo el siguiente error:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: b.call is not a function
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ajax.event.js:263)
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
each @ jquery.min.js:2
each @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ ajax.event.js:263
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery.min.js:3
```

esta linea:

```
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ajax.event.js:263)
```

se refiera a esta:

```
var $form       = $form.each('select').prop('disabled', false);
```

**Como lo soluciono ??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo resolví agregando este código:

```
        var inputs = $("input[readonly]");
        $.each(inputs, function (obj, v) {
            var name = $(v).attr("name");
            var val = $(v).val();
            formData.append(name, val);
        });
        var selects = $("select[disabled]");
        $.each(selects, function (obj, v) {
            var name = $(v).attr("name");
            var val = $(v).val()
            formData.append(name, val);
        });
```